# How can I check if a document is currently opened/being viewed by an editor or not?

Tags: google-apps-script

In order to prevent reformatting and processing of incomplete/unfinished data, I would like to check if a google spreadsheet is currently opened by an editor or not. I could not find an api function for it and was wondering if it is even possible to do it. In the case it isn't, does anybody have an idea of how to achieve similar functionality without making it to complex for the users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not in Google apps script , but real time api could help you https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/

changing sharing or ownership on completion of edit coulld be used to indicate completion of work, as could noting state in text or description property

Comment: thanks, thats how I actually solved it. The users now have to indicate when they initiate or finish editing by setting/unsetting the value of a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear  why you need to detect that or why its useful to you but no you cant tell who has it open. How would that help you? A user could come back later and keep editing or might have finished but left the window open all night. You are not covering either.